# Using OSX Terminal, how can I remove any line in a CSV if there is a partial match to a txt file containing strings?

Tags: macos, csv, terminal, grep

I have a file 'data.csv' with thousands of lines that needs to be filtered against a text file 'blacklist.txt' that also has thousands of lines.

If a line in data.csv is a partial match for any line in blacklist.txt, it should be removed.

The results should be saved in new csv file 'data-filtered.csv'

Here are some sample lines from data.csv:

```
"apple","orange","banana","","","","fruit"
"pork","beef","chicken","turkey","shrimp","fish","meat"
"green beans","peas","carrots","lettuce","","","veggies"
"milk","cheese","yogurt","sour cream","","","dairy"
```

And sample data from blacklist.txt:

```
meat
yogurt
```

I want to filter the data.csv against blacklist.txt so only these lines would be added to a new csv file 'data-filtered.csv' like this:

```
"apple","orange","banana","","","","fruit"
"green beans","peas","carrots","lettuce","","","veggies"
```

I've tried using grep but can't get it to work, here is one command I tried: grep -v blacklist.txt data.csv > data-filtered.csv

The resulting file has all of the original lines in data.csv and nothing is filtered.

Comment: You should really put more thought into your example so it includes non-trivial cases. For the most obvious example - include a case where data.csv contains `"pineapple"` and blacklist.txt contains `apple` and show the expected output for that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this close:

```
grep -vFf blacklist.txt data.csv > data-filtered.csv
```

Comment: Tried it with -vFf, I am getting an error: grep: illegal byte sequence

Any idea what would cause that?

Comment: I'm offline but search for "LC_ALL" and `tr` on here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark.  I tried searching and found recommendations to prefix commands with LC_ALL=C.

Now I am running the same command with that prefix and get this error:  grep: empty (sub)expression

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You probably have a blank line in your blacklist file.... or a bracket or asterisk or somesuch. Try with a really small simple blacklist file.

Comment: If data.csv contains `"pineapple"` and blacklist.txt contains `apple` then that `pineapple` line would be excluded from the output. I'm guessing that would be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to avoid partial matches, e.g. `apple` matching `pineapple`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{bl=(NR>1 ? bl "|" : "") "\""$0"\""; next} !($0 ~ bl)' blacklist.txt data.csv
```

Look:

```
$ cat data.csv
"pineapple","orange","banana","","","","fruit"
"pork","beef","chicken","turkey","shrimp","fish","meat"
"green beans","peas","carrots","lettuce","","","veggies"
"milk","cheese","yogurt","sour cream","","","dairy"

$ cat blacklist.txt
apple
meat
yogurt

$ awk 'NR==FNR{bl=(NR>1 ? bl "|" : "") "\""$0"\""; next} !($0 ~ bl)' blacklist.txt data.csv
"pineapple","orange","banana","","","","fruit"
"green beans","peas","carrots","lettuce","","","veggies"

$ grep -vFf blacklist.txt data.csv
"green beans","peas","carrots","lettuce","","","veggies"
```